# How to convert SQL Left Join query to Linq to Entity in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-entities

I have a Table: `Material(ID,Name,MAterialParentID)`

```
SELECT  c1.ID,c1.Name as ParentName,c2.id,c2.Name
FROM    Material c1 Left JOIN Material c2
ON      c1.ID = c2.MaterialParentID

ID  ParentName  id  Name
1   Aluminium   2   Cavity
1   Aluminium   3   Copper
1   Aluminium   4   Flooring
2   Cavity     NULL NULL
3   Copper     NULL NULL
4   Flooring   NULL NULL
5   Glass      NULL NULL
```

**I want to convert the above `SQL Query` to `Linq Query` using Liq to Entities.**

Help Appreciated!

Comment: @Matthew You use `Include` on a navigation property, not the foreign key itself.

Comment: yes, too late to edit now unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

if the table is only for reading you could simply create a view and then when using reverse engineering make sure you have views imported.

or if you did want this done in LINQ here is the MSDN example

```
var innerJoinQuery =
    from cust in customers
    join dist in distributors on cust.City equals dist.City
    select new { CustomerName = cust.Name, DistributorName = dist.Name };
```

this is how yours would look

```
var Material = from M in db.Materials
                       join M2 in db.Materials on M.ID equals M2.MaterialParentID
                       select new {ParentID = M.ID, ParentName = M.Name, M2.ID, M2.Name };
```

i have edited my post above as you can see i have included the ParentID to make all columns unique

Comment: hello @Luke Franklin, i have edited your query in your answer line and used in my program. but it shows error:"anonymous types cant have multiple properties with same name' at M2.ID! how to resolve it? any idea?

Comment: It's because the way you will then get the values will be materials.id and there will be 2 ids write at the start of m.id. Parentid = m.id

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of problem [linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net) is your friend.

I'd suggest something like:

```
var materials = (from m in context.Material 
                let moreMaterials = (from m2 in context.Material where m2.id == m.id select m2).FirstOrDefault()
                select m).ToList();
```

But you can use linqpad to customise to your query requirements.